# Sort a multi-dimensional array based on an ordered array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

This seems the oldest question in the book with hundreds of resources available, but so far each solution I have tried has not solved my problem. I'm hoping you can help.

I'm trying to display a graph that displays the last 31 days of data. The outputted array looks like this:

```
$data[
    0 =>
       'day' => 10,
       'amount' => 5,
       'count' => 2
    1 =>
       'day' => 16,
       'amount' => 4,
       'count' => 2
    2 =>
       'day' => 21,
       'amount' => 16,
       'count' => 1
    3 =>
       'day' => 11,
       'amount' => 0,
       'count' => 0
    4 =>
       'day' => 12,
       'amount' => 0,
       'count' => 0
]
```

Essentially this array is composed of two parts. The first 3 inner arrays are days that contain amounts and counts, the remaining 27 are any unaccounted for days with their amounts and counts set to 0. So for example `$data[5]` will be day 13 and `$data[21]` day 31. `$data[22]` will then equal day 1, going up to day 9 thus therefore showing the last 31 days.

In addition there is an ordered array of the days we want to output.

```
$days[
    0 =>
        'day' => 10
    1 =>
        'day' => 11
    2 =>
        'day' => 12
    ...
    30 =>
        'day' => 9
]
```

I have tried the below but whilst `$data` is now ordered, it's essentially just a replica of `$days` and loses the other values held in `$data`.

```
$data = array_uintersect($days, $data, array($this, 'compare_days'));

function compare_days($order, $array) {
    return strcmp($order['day'], $array['day']);
}
```

What's up? How can I sort `$data` so that it retains the data and orders it as desired in `$days`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [**`uasort`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) as

```
uasort($data, function($a,$b) use ($days){
    foreach($days as $value){
        if($a['day'] == $value['day']){
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        if($b['day'] == $value['day']){
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/414480)

Comment: This is good and sorts as intended, so thank you! The only issue now is (and I did not mention this in my post so my apologies) running a `json_encode($data)` returns `{"5":{"day":"10","amount":"0","donations":"0"},"2":{"day":"11"...` which instead needs to read `[{"day":"10"...}]`. I'm guessing it's because the array is now "unordered" in terms of index key. Would you any idea?

Comment: Sorry can't get you can you post the original array along with the expected output

Comment: All is fine. I solved it with `echo json_encode(array_values($graph));` which fortunately resets the array indexes to be sequential. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.Glad it helped you. And also for sequential array indexes simply use `usort` if you need main index to be `0,1,..`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $days[$key]  = $row['day'];
    $amount[$key] =  $row['amount'];
}

array_multisort($days, SORT_ASC, $amount, SORT_ASC, $data);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: This sorts by day in ascending order (1 to 31). The day actually starts on the 10th Jul (10th Aug - 31 days) and then works its way back up to the 10th August.