# Sort bash array following an ordered array pattern

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have an array, let's call it `ensembldb` that has the following lines:

```
rs2799070   ENST00000379389 ENSG00000187608 ISG15   inframe_insertion   NA  NA  protein_coding  ISG15   ubiquitin-like  modifier    [Source:HGNC    Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4053]NM_005101.3    NP_005092
rs2799070   ENST00000458555 ENSG00000224969 AL645608.2  missense_variant    NA  NA  antisense   NA  NULL    NULL
rs2799070   ENST00000624652 ENSG00000187608 ISG15   inframe_deletion    NA  NA  protein_coding  ISG15   ubiquitin-like  modifier    [Source:HGNC    Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4053]NULL   NULL
rs2799070   ENST00000624697 ENSG00000187608 ISG15   frameshift_variant  NA  NA  protein_coding  ISG15   ubiquitin-like  modifier    [Source:HGNC    Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4053]NULL   NULL
```

and another [ordered array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161323/how-to-keep-associative-array-order-in-bash), let's call it `ordered_array`:

```
frameshift_variant
missense_variant
inframe_insertion
inframe_deletion
```

I would like to order my array `ensembldb` to match the orders in array `ordered_array`. The output expected is the following:

```
rs2799070   ENST00000624697 ENSG00000187608 ISG15   frameshift_variant  NA  NA  protein_coding  ISG15   ubiquitin-like  modifier    [Source:HGNC    Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4053]NULL   NULL
rs2799070   ENST00000458555 ENSG00000224969 AL645608.2  missense_variant    NA  NA  antisense   NA  NULL    NULL
rs2799070   ENST00000379389 ENSG00000187608 ISG15   inframe_insertion   NA  NA  protein_coding  ISG15   ubiquitin-like  modifier    [Source:HGNC    Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4053]NM_005101.3    NP_005092
rs2799070   ENST00000624652 ENSG00000187608 ISG15   inframe_deletion    NA  NA  protein_coding  ISG15   ubiquitin-like  modifier    [Source:HGNC    Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4053]NULL   NULL
```

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912344/sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-an-ordered-array) but it doesn't answer my question as it is a multidimensional array. How can I order my array `ensembldb` according to the ordered array `ordered_array` ?

Thank you.

**Edit 1:** Adding code as requested by @anubhava

```
declare -A ordered_array
ordered_array[0]="frameshift_variant"
ordered_array[1]="missense_variant"
ordered_array[2]="inframe_insertion"
ordered_array[3]="inframe_deletion"

while read -r LINE; do
    chrom=$(echo -e "$LINE" | cut -f1 -d$'\t' | sed 's/^chr//g')
    pos=$(echo -e "$LINE" | cut -f2 -d$'\t')
    ref=$(echo -e "$LINE" | cut -f3 -d$'\t')
    alt=$(echo -e "$LINE" | cut -f4 -d$'\t')
    LINE=$(echo -e "$LINE" | sed 's/^chr//g')
    ensembldb=$(echo "PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT Annotated_ID, Transcript, Gene_ID, Gene_name, Consequence, Swissprot_ID, AA_change, Biotype, Gene_description, RefSeq_mRNA, RefSeq_peptide FROM SNP_annot.37_annot_ensembl_89_full_descr where chrom = \"$chrom\" and Start = \"$pos\" and Local_alleles = \"$ref/$alt\"'; execute stmt1;" | mariadb -A -N)
    readarray -t array <<< "$ensembldb"
    pos19=$(echo "PREPARE stmt2 FROM 'select hg19_pos from SNP_annot.mut_convert_pos where chrom = \"$chrom\" and hg38_pos = \"$pos\"'; execute stmt2;" | mariadb -A -N)
    hits=$(echo -e "$ensembldb" | wc -l)
    [ ! -z "$pos19" ] && awk -v line="$LINE" -v pos="$pos19" -v ensembl="$ensembldb" -v hit="$hits" 'BEGIN {print line"\t"ensembl"\t"hit"\t"pos}'
done
```

1.The variable `LINE` has rows like this:

```
CHROM   POS REF ALT QUAL    DP  Genotype
chr1    16495   G   C   1722.77 252 G/C
chr1    16719   T   A   145.77  189 T/A
chr1    16841   G   T   701.77  521 G/T
chr1    17626   G   A   154.77  124 G/A
```

2.The variable `ensembldb` is a MySQL query that returns multiple rows and converted to an array. It contains rows that I want to sort according to `ordered_array` and pick the first row that matches `ordered_array`.

Comment: @anubhava I added some code. Hopefully it's clear.

Comment: @Law Some feedback on my answer would be nice. Doesn't it do what you want? :)

Comment: @mickp I am trying it right now, I will let you know asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` might work for you:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$5]=$0;next}{print a[$1]}' file_a file_b
```

If `a` and `b` are really arrays:

```
readarray -t a < <(awk 'FNR==NR{a[$5]=$0;next}{print a[$1]}' <(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${b[@]}"))
```

Comment: Could you please give some explanation on the command ? thank you in advance

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be passing the arrays for awk as awk variables with `-v` argument ?

Comment: First of all, does the solution work for you? :) No point in explaining if it doesn't work.

Comment: No, the solution is not working for me, sorry. I tried doing `readarray -t a < <(awk 'FNR==NR{ensembldb[$5]=$0;next}{print ensembldb[$1]}' <(printf '%s\n' "${ensembldb[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${ordered_array[@]}"))` and `echo "$a"` nothing's returned

Comment: Show the input properly in your question. For example what your `a` variable contains. It is not an array as I can see now after your edit BTW.

Comment: ok actually I take back what I said, your proposed answer works. The example that I was trying didn't contain the information in ordered array thus not printing anything. I am accepting the answer. Thank you !

Comment: I did say that my array `A` what type of rows it contains. It is just that my file has thousands of lines that have multiple type of consequences. The list of ordered array contains in total 34 unique strings.